# Different result from compare 2 arrays

Tags: javascript

How do I compare 2 arrays with the current results:

1. only the values from `a` that are not values in `b`
2. only the values from `b` that are not values in `a`

   `var a = [15404300,1567727156,3164959543,92767925,309935495,2759310935,989025462,3109960889,2232537998,67833886,23514543,86720742,837670914,338878286,2598297517,32190488,3292414118,558573564,2813085991,118447616,2380667550];`

   `var b = [3292414118,2598297517,123];`

Current code

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
        if (a[i] == b[j]) {

        }
        if(b[j] !== a[i]){

        }
    }
}
```

Solution for JSON objects

```
var a = [{ data: 15404300, id: 0 },{ data: 1567727156, id: 0 },{ data: 3164959543, id: 0 },{ data: 92767925, id: 0 },{ data: 3181200014, id: 0 },{ data: 3292414118, id: 1 },{ data: 2598297517, id: 2 }];
var b = [{ data: 3292414118, id: 1 },  { data: 2598297517, id: 2 },  { data: 123, id: 3 }];


a.forEach(function(key) { 

    var keyData = key.data;
    if (-1 === b.map(function(d) { return d['data']; }).indexOf(keyData)) {

       res.push(key);
    }

}, this);
```

Comment: what you have tried already ??

Comment: @Wand Maker  tried that already, result is a combination of both a and b difference, I need explicit result a without b and b without a

Comment: Seems like everyone is jumping with negative ratings without reading what I said.

Comment: @Alex_TNT Okay, I retracted my vote. Though I did not downvote your question, I kind of understand why people down voted it - it is not very clear what you needed - it requires one to read the question 2 or 3 times to figure it out Pls refer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  It always helps to give simpler examples of input and expected output

Comment: @WandMaker Maker 2nd comment was not referring to you. It was general. Though I don't know how I would explain it better than I've currently done

Comment: @Alex_TNT 1.  Use input arrays to be of size that are sufficient to demonstrate your point.  2. Use elements of array that are easy to comprehend - currently you are using very high integer values, which is unnecessary noise.  For example:  Use `var arr1 = ['a','b','c'];` and something similar for 2nd array.  3.  Show clearly what is expected output for given input.   4.  If needed, provide more than one example.   In absence of clear problems, most answers will end up speculative (given that (not all, but most) people answer to earn reputation and want to be first one to answer :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//a-b:
var res = []; // the resulting array

a.forEach(function(key) {
  if (-1 === b.indexOf(key)) {
    res.push(key);
  }
}, this);
```

For b-a just swap a and b in the example.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed. In abobe example a-b length is 19 , b-a length is 1

Comment: Do you mind if I ask, if I have a array like this `{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"} ` how the code would work in order to compare just firstName and push the whole object

Comment: this is another question. These are not arrays but objects. Then you could traverse over each object (map, foreach or for) and make two new arrays containing what you need or you can make a search with two loops

Comment: Thank you for explanation, seems I'm back to square one, I needed additional properties inside object

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to this.

```
var resA = [];
a.forEach(function(v,i){ if( b.indexOf(v) < 0) resA.push(v)});
var resB = [];
b.forEach(function(v,i){ if( a.indexOf(v) < 0) resB.push(v)});
```

or in an more clean way using filter

```
var resA = a.filter(function(v){ if(b.indexOf(v) < 0) return v ; });
var resB = b.filter(function(v){ if(a.indexOf(v) < 0) return v ; });
```